# How to use Yarn schedulers and queues ?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I need to access Yarn schedulers and queues from java programs to change the priority of submitted MR-jobs. Is it possible ? And if it is, please help with some code snippets.

Similar codes for older map-reduce are also welcome.

Comment: I tried using the job priority like in MR1 and it did nothing :(